# What's the best tools or technique to test non-regression of calculated data in web application

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

I will start working on non regression testing of a tracking web application. The purpose of test automation is to validate the non-regression of calculated and generated values by the application under test between two versions of the same application. As this is my first time testing this type of application, I'm not sure if selenium is the right tool to do these tests. Has anyone done a test like this before? Could you suggest other tools or testing techniques?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to test data generated by the app is to calculate that data before the test and compare the results. For that you can use an excel sheet or a CSV file to have your pre-calculated data at and then run your tests to compare row by row against your system.

Also you must ensure that your code is thread safe because you will probably need to run it in parallel. You will need to use ThreadLocal for all of your local objects.

I would have wrote an example for you but I don't know anything about your system.

Lastly, good luck with that task.

Comment: Thank you Sharaf for your feedback.